# Pushing a docker repo - specify tag - or just repo name?

Tags: docker

When building a docker image repo locally, I have several tags.

When I want to push the "whole lot" up to the docker hub - I can run:

```
docker push myrepo
```

But the push command also allows you to narrow it down to specific tags. Is there any reason someone would want to do this? It means leaving data, presumably in the local repo, but if the remote registry already has the image, then pushing is a no-op anyway - so I am not sure why one would specify a tag when pushing - am I mistaken?

Comment: What do you mean with "pushing is a no-op anyway". From my point of view, you can have multiple docker images for the same app, and maybe you only want to push/publish one of them (for example, myuser/myapp:v1, myuser/myapp:v2 and myuser/myapp:internal_alpha).

Comment: oh - say I have a repo: foo/bar, and it has tags tag1, tag2, tag3. I only made a change to tag2, tag1 and 3 are the same locally and in the registry. I can run docker push foo/bar - or docker push foo/bar:tag2 - the latter one is quite a bit quicker as the other ones seem to do a lot of roundtrips to the registry and back checking the other tags - yet there is no material change.